# Can someone advise on simplifying a MySQL query so it doesn't take minutes to execute and/or display incorrect results

Tags: mysql

We are using SugarCRM with ZuckerReports at the office and need a specific statistic coming out.

The issue lies within my MYSQL query.

If I use the following query

```
SELECT 
  accounts.id,
  accounts.name AS AccountName,
  (SELECT 
  accounts_audit.`after_value_string` 
  FROM accounts_audit 
  WHERE accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c' AND 
  accounts_audit.date_created < CONCAT(CAST(2012 AS CHAR(4)),'-',LPAD(CAST(3 AS CHAR(2)),2,'0'),'-01 00:00:00') AND
  accounts_audit.after_value_string<>'Active' AND 
  accounts_audit.after_value_string<>'Semi' AND
  accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id
  ORDER BY accounts_audit.date_created 
  LIMIT 1) AS PreviousStatus,
  (SELECT 
  accounts_audit.after_value_string 
  FROM accounts_audit
  WHERE accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c' AND 
  MONTH(accounts_audit.date_created) = 3 AND
  YEAR(accounts_audit.date_created) = 2012 AND
  (accounts_audit.after_value_string='Active' OR 
  accounts_audit.after_value_string='Semi') AND
  accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id
  ORDER BY accounts_audit.date_created DESC
  LIMIT 1) AS NextStatus,
  (SELECT 
  COUNT(tp_trade_profile.awb_number) 
  FROM tp_trade_profile 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tp_trade_prile_accounts_c ON (tp_trade_profile.id = tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.tp_trade_p7fc3profile_ida) 
  WHERE tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.deleted = 0 
  AND tp_trade_profile.deleted = 0 
  AND MONTH(tp_trade_profile.date_shipping)=3
  AND YEAR(tp_trade_profile.date_shipping)=2012
  AND tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.tp_trade_p2584ccounts_idb =accounts.id) AS SHIPMENTS,
  accounts_cstm.area_code_c
FROM
  accounts
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (accounts.assigned_user_id = users.id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts_cstm ON (accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c)
WHERE
      users.user_name = 'USER1'
GROUP BY
      accounts.id
```

it runs realtively fast but also the result shows     NULL    rows in    NextStatus    .
If I add the same check for

> NextStatus

in the

> PreviousStatus

query, but omitting the NULLs, it takes around 20 minutes to finish and show only NULLs for

> NextStatus

and

> PreviousStatus

Here's the modified query:

```
SELECT 
  accounts.id,
  accounts.name AS AccountName,
  (SELECT 
  accounts_audit.`after_value_string` 
  FROM accounts_audit 
  WHERE accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c' AND 
  accounts_audit.date_created < CONCAT(CAST(2012 AS CHAR(4)),'-',LPAD(CAST(3 AS CHAR(2)),2,'0'),'-01 00:00:00') AND
  accounts_audit.after_value_string<>'Active' AND 
  accounts_audit.after_value_string<>'Semi' AND
  accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id AND
  (SELECT accounts_audit.after_value_string 
      FROM accounts_audit 
      WHERE     
      accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c' 
      AND MONTH(accounts_audit.date_created) = 3 
      AND YEAR(accounts_audit.date_created) = 2012 
      AND (accounts_audit.after_value_string='Active' OR accounts_audit.after_value_string='Semi') 
      AND accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id 
      ORDER BY accounts_audit.date_created DESC LIMIT 1)<>NULL
  ORDER BY accounts_audit.date_created 
  LIMIT 1) AS PreviousStatus,
  (SELECT 
  accounts_audit.after_value_string 
  FROM accounts_audit
  WHERE accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c' AND 
  MONTH(accounts_audit.date_created) = 3 AND
  YEAR(accounts_audit.date_created) = 2012 AND
  (accounts_audit.after_value_string='Active' OR 
  accounts_audit.after_value_string='Semi') AND
  accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id
  ORDER BY accounts_audit.date_created DESC
  LIMIT 1) AS NextStatus,
  (SELECT 
  COUNT(tp_trade_profile.awb_number) 
  FROM tp_trade_profile 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tp_trade_prile_accounts_c ON (tp_trade_profile.id = tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.tp_trade_p7fc3profile_ida) 
  WHERE tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.deleted = 0 
  AND tp_trade_profile.deleted = 0 
  AND MONTH(tp_trade_profile.date_shipping)=3
  AND YEAR(tp_trade_profile.date_shipping)=2012
  AND tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.tp_trade_p2584ccounts_idb =accounts.id) AS SHIPMENTS,
  accounts_cstm.area_code_c
FROM
  accounts
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (accounts.assigned_user_id = users.id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts_cstm ON (accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c)
WHERE
      users.user_name = 'USER1'
GROUP BY
      accounts.id
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction here?

Also the 4 tables that we use have between 30000 and 50000 records each.
Thanks in advance!

Ok, I noticed that I am actually filtering records only in one of the subqueries and thus the NULLs in the result. After moving a filter to the main conditions:

```
SELECT 
  accounts.id,
  accounts.name AS AccountName,
  (SELECT 
  accounts_audit.`after_value_string` 
  FROM accounts_audit 
  WHERE accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c' AND 
  accounts_audit.date_created < CONCAT(CAST(2012 AS CHAR(4)),'-',LPAD(CAST(3 AS CHAR(2)),2,'0'),'-01 00:00:00') AND
  accounts_audit.after_value_string<>'Active' AND 
  accounts_audit.after_value_string<>'Semi' AND
  accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id
  ORDER BY accounts_audit.date_created 
  LIMIT 1) AS PreviousStatus,
  (SELECT 
  accounts_audit.after_value_string 
  FROM accounts_audit
  WHERE accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c' AND 
  MONTH(accounts_audit.date_created) = 3 AND
  YEAR(accounts_audit.date_created) = 2012 AND
  (accounts_audit.after_value_string='Active' OR 
  accounts_audit.after_value_string='Semi') AND
  accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id
  ORDER BY accounts_audit.date_created DESC
  LIMIT 1) AS NextStatus,
  (SELECT 
  COUNT(tp_trade_profile.awb_number) 
  FROM tp_trade_profile 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tp_trade_prile_accounts_c ON (tp_trade_profile.id = tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.tp_trade_p7fc3profile_ida) 
  WHERE tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.deleted = 0 
  AND tp_trade_profile.deleted = 0 
  AND MONTH(tp_trade_profile.date_shipping)=3
  AND YEAR(tp_trade_profile.date_shipping)=2012
  AND tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.tp_trade_p2584ccounts_idb =accounts.id) AS SHIPMENTS,
  accounts_cstm.area_code_c
FROM
  accounts
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON (accounts.assigned_user_id = users.id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts_cstm ON (accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c)
WHERE
      users.user_name = 'USER1' AND
      accounts.id IN (SELECT 
                      b.parent_id
                      FROM
                      accounts_audit b
                      WHERE
                      b.field_name = 'statuses_c' AND 
                      MONTH(b.date_created) = 3 AND 
                      YEAR(b.date_created) = 2012 AND 
                      (b.after_value_string = 'Active' OR 
                      b.after_value_string = 'Semi')
                      GROUP BY  parent_id ORDER BY  b.date_created)
GROUP BY
      accounts.id
```

I've got 45 mins of execution/at least, so far/ and no result :(

**UPDATE:**

Here's some info about the tables:

The `accounts` table holds `name` and `id`(along other info that's not in this situation.

The `accounts_audit` table holds `parent_id` and statuses along with their dates of update.

The `tp_trade_profile` contains shipment info.

The `tp_trade_prile_accounts_c` holds shipment id and the id of the account(form `accounts`) that is the owner of the shipment.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I think the problem is that your fields are not properly indexed which is causing MySQL to perform full table scans unnecessarily.

In general, you want to index fields that will be used to filter rows. Since you're using the following fields to filter rows, you'll want to add indexes to them:

```
accounts_audit.field_name
accounts_audit.date_created
accounts_audit.after_value_string

accounts_cstm.id_c

tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.deleted

tp_trade_profile.deleted
tp_trade_profile.date_shipping
```

This may take a while so you may want to schedule this to run overnight.

Here are a couple of articles which explain "when to index" better than I can:

- http://hackmysql.com/case1
- http://www.howtoforge.com/when-to-use-indexes-in-mysql-databases
- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/

**UPDATE:**

After playing with the fiddle (and inserting some more junk data into `accounts_audit` to accommodate earlier dates than October), I think this will do what you want. I named the first session variable `@quarter` because your original query was using March 1st. Obviously, you'll probably want to rename it to accurately reflect what that date actually represents.

To do the joins on to `account` I simply moved the appropriate `AND` clause into the `ON` condition.

If this doesn't work for you, please describe what you are trying to get in the report.

New fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/0f294/1

```
-- Define basic variables so other queries are not casting a constant
SELECT      (@quarter:=CAST('2012-10-01' AS DATETIME));
SELECT      (@month:=MONTH(@quarter));
SELECT      (@year:=YEAR(@quarter));

-- Get @PreviousStatus:
SELECT      (@PreviousStatus:=accounts_audit.after_value_string)
FROM        accounts_audit
            LEFT JOIN accounts
                ON accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id
WHERE       accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c'
            AND accounts_audit.date_created < @quarter
            AND accounts_audit.after_value_string NOT IN ('Active', 'Semi')
ORDER BY    accounts_audit.date_created 
LIMIT 1;

-- Get @NextStatus:
SELECT      (@NextStatus:=accounts_audit.after_value_string)
FROM        accounts_audit
            LEFT JOIN accounts
                ON accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id
WHERE       accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c'
            AND MONTH(accounts_audit.date_created) = @month
            AND YEAR(accounts_audit.date_created) = @year
            AND accounts_audit.after_value_string IN ('Active', 'Semi')
ORDER BY    accounts_audit.date_created DESC
LIMIT 1;

-- Get @SHIPMENTS:
SELECT      (@SHIPMENTS:=COUNT(tp_trade_profile.awb_number))
FROM        tp_trade_profile
            LEFT JOIN tp_trade_prile_accounts_c
                ON tp_trade_profile.id = tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.tp_trade_p7fc3profile_ida
            LEFT JOIN accounts
                ON tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.tp_trade_p2584ccounts_idb = accounts.id
WHERE       tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.deleted = 0
            AND tp_trade_profile.deleted = 0
            AND MONTH(tp_trade_profile.date_shipping) = @month
            AND YEAR(tp_trade_profile.date_shipping) = @year;
-- All three statements above should execute very quickly.

-- Statement below generates rest of audit report and should run very quickly as well.
SELECT      accounts.id
            , accounts.name AS AccountName
            , @PreviousStatus AS PreviousStatus
            , @NextStatus AS NextStatus
            , @SHIPMENTS AS SHIPMENTS
            , accounts_cstm.area_code_c
FROM        accounts
            LEFT OUTER JOIN users
                ON accounts.assigned_user_id = users.id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts_cstm
                ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c
WHERE       users.user_name = 'USER1'
GROUP BY    accounts.id;
```

**ORIGINAL:**

I would break it down into individual statements (easier to read and to debug):

```
DECLARE     @PreviousStatus     varchar(50);
DECLARE     @NextStatus         varchar(50);
DECLARE     @SHIPMENTS          int;

--Get @PreviousStatus
SELECT      (@PreviousStatus:=accounts_audit.after_value_string)
FROM        accounts_audit 
WHERE       accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c'
            AND accounts_audit.date_created < CAST('2012-03-01' AS DATETIME)
            AND accounts_audit.after_value_string NOT IN ('Active', 'Semi')
            AND accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id
ORDER BY    accounts_audit.date_created 
LIMIT 1

--Get @NextStatus:
SELECT      (@NextStatus:=accounts_audit.after_value_string)
FROM        accounts_audit
WHERE       accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c'
            AND MONTH(accounts_audit.date_created) = 3
            AND YEAR(accounts_audit.date_created) = 2012
            AND accounts_audit.after_value_string IN ('Active', 'Semi')
            AND accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id
ORDER BY    accounts_audit.date_created DESC
LIMIT 1

--Get @SHIPMENTS::
SELECT      (@SHIPMENTS:=COUNT(tp_trade_profile.awb_number))
FROM        tp_trade_profile
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tp_trade_prile_accounts_c
                ON tp_trade_profile.id = tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.tp_trade_p7fc3profile_ida
WHERE       tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.deleted = 0
            AND tp_trade_profile.deleted = 0
            AND MONTH(tp_trade_profile.date_shipping) = 3
            AND YEAR(tp_trade_profile.date_shipping) = 2012
            AND tp_trade_prile_accounts_c.tp_trade_p2584ccounts_idb =accounts.id
--All three statements above should execute very quickly.

--Statement below generates rest of audit report and should run very quickly as well.
SELECT      accounts.id
            , accounts.name AS AccountName
            , @PreviousStatus AS PreviousStatus
            , @NextStatus AS NextStatus
            , @SHIPMENTS AS SHIPMENTS
            , accounts_cstm.area_code_c
FROM        accounts
            LEFT OUTER JOIN users
                ON accounts.assigned_user_id = users.id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts_cstm
                ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c
WHERE       users.user_name = 'USER1'
GROUP BY    accounts.id
```

The statements above should produce the same report as in your OP. I cannot say for sure as I have not tested it (nor am I a MySQL user, I use SQL Server 2000 to 2008 normally, although according to MySQL docs it should work).

This structure also allows extremely easy modification to individual queries so you can run this separately:

```
--Get @NextStatus:
SELECT      (@NextStatus:=accounts_audit.after_value_string)
FROM        accounts_audit
WHERE       accounts_audit.field_name = 'statuses_c'
            AND MONTH(accounts_audit.date_created) = 3
            AND YEAR(accounts_audit.date_created) = 2012
            AND accounts_audit.after_value_string IN ('Active', 'Semi')
            AND accounts_audit.parent_id = accounts.id
ORDER BY    accounts_audit.date_created DESC
LIMIT 1
```

and change it as needed to ensure non-NULL rows are returned.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It really is much much easier to read and debug this way!    
The thing is the `accounts.id` in each of the `--Get` sections comes from the `accounts` table.
Because the requested result must be a list of all the accounts with their `Previous` and `Next` statuses and shipments.
I think I still need a join or nested select(maybe?) in each section to get statuses for all the accounts.
Am I making a big mistake in the nested select logic?

Comment: I've also updated the question with some explanation about the tables that get queried.

Comment: Yes, you'll likely need to do a join on `accounts`. Is there any chance you can set up a fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/ with junk data in the tables?

Comment: Is this good enough - [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/5da02/1) - or should I include some more data?

Comment: @nnikolov06: Good enough for me :). I added more junk data to `accounts_audit` so make sure that the `@PreviousStatus` session variable would return non-null data.

Comment: it runs very well. It's very vast. The thing thay I have to achieve though is a list with all `accounts` and their statuses at a given date(month in this scenario).
The `accounts_audit` holds the statuses for all the accounts. Each status could change at any moment based on a logic. So there are many statuses for each account. So the with the `@NextStatus` I'm trying to get the latest account status in the queried month. `@PreviousStatus` must get the latest status which was set before the queried month. And `@SHIPMENTS` get number of shipments for each account in the queried month.

Comment: The trouble(I think) is that all queries must be joined to get data for each separate company. Also the `accounts` table has ~20000 rows the `tp_trade_profile` and `tp_trade_prile_accounts_c` >50000 and growing as time progresses. The `accounts_audit` has about 10000 rows of these statuses and also >40000 rows of other statuses that are not used in this scenario.    For example:   
`Test Account 1` is now `Active`, was `Gone`, has `4` shipments  and is in `Area1`.`Test Account 3` is now `Active`, was `Inactive`, has `1` and is in `Area2`.

Comment: The joins shouldn't be an issue. Which fields are indexed on the DB?

Comment: Here are the indexes on the specified tables: [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/C0XNm1XN)